Two bibliographies of different styles in one document separated after one another
I have a book-document where I write a lot of chapters and have a bibliography of a certain style at the end of the chapters. Then I add an appendix.
After some sections in the appendix, I have a new bibliography in a different natbib style.
I have the following code to indicate what I want to achieve:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{natbib} % for first bibliography
\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} % for second bibliography

\begin{filecontents}{references1.bib}
@misc{A:2015,
  author = {Alpha, A.},
  year = {2015},
  title = {Title A},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references2.bib}
@misc{A:2015,
  author = {Alpha, A.},
  year = {2015},
  title = {Title A},
}
@misc{B:2017,
  author = {Beta, B.},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Title B},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
    Some text using \citet{A:2015} and some more text \citep{A:2015}.

\chapter{Second chapter}
    Some more text here as well \citep{A:2015}.

\label{First bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{references1}

\chapter{Appendices}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Content that needs an extra bibliography
\section{Appendix section 1}
   Here is some extra text, that talks about \citet{B:2017}.

\section*{Appendix section 2}
   And some more text \citep{A:2015}.

\label{Second bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references2}  % in file references.bib
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}

I am using LuaLaTeX and would like to not change that.
There are duplicates in the references.bib-files. These duplicates should appear in the second bibliography as well.

AFAIK neither multibib nor chapterbib or bibunits supports usage of different natbib options for different bibliographies. The package can be loaded only once and does not support changing of the load-time options at run-time. Different bibliography styles are supported (as long as they don't need different natbib package options). See the manuals of the packages for more information. If possible, I would also suggest to consider biblatex.

Would it be possible to use the same bibliography styles with any of the mentioned options?
